# django not work alert

Tags: javascript, django

django 2.0.2
mac os 10.13
python 3.6.4

i want use alert to templates

```
django settings.py

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
messages.DEBUG: 'alert-info',
messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
}
 
views.py
def list(request)
    messages.error(request,'invalid user', extra_tags='alert')
    return redirect('/')

templates.html
```

i tried in 2 ways

template1.html

```
 {% if messages %}
  <script>
  {% for message in messages %}
  alert({{message}})
  {% endfor %}
  </script>
  {% endif %}
```

template2.html

```
<div class="content container">
  {% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
  <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    {{ message }}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
```

template2.html result this:

[image]

```
<div class="alert alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        invalid user
      </div>
```

html code for this image
this html is valid ??

I can not use alert in django..

Comment: The screenshot image is useless to us. Instead post the relevant rendered html output. Use "view source" in your web browser to get the plain html.

Answer (score 0):

The template code looks valid. Your problem is probably that you have not successfully any added messages in your view function.

The usage of messages is explained in the docs. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#using-messages-in-views-and-templates

`messages.ERROR` is not a function, it's just the constant numerical code `50`
To add an error message, use the function `messages.error()`.

```
views.py

from django.contrib import messages

def list(request):
    messages.error(request,'invalid user', extra_tags='alert')
    return redirect('/')
```

Your `list` view should have caused an exception. It's invalid syntax (missing `:` in def statement) and also the number messages.ERROR is not callable.

Comment: image in post is result of the use messages.error() not alert just text